# angularjs does not filter other pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple code which get employees from controller and I want to filter these records with pagination. When I filter on first page everything works fine but, when I want to filter from other page it does not filter and shows nothing.

My code is as follow:

-filter.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('MyController', function ($scope, EmployeesService) {
    $scope.Employees = null;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; 
    $scope.pageSize = 2;
    $scope.maxSize = 100;


    EmployeesService.GetEmployees().then(function (d) {
        $scope.Employees = d.data; // Success

    }, function () {
        alert('Failed'); // Failed
    })
})

.service('EmployeesService', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.GetEmployees = function () {
        return $http.get('/Employees/GetEmployees');
    }
    return service;
})
.filter('start', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);

    };
});
```

-Index.cshtml

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" name="searchString" placeholder="Search for names.." class="form-control"><br />

        <div ng-repeat="emp in Employees |orderBy: 'employeeName'| filter: filterText | start: (currentPage-1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize"
             class="alert alert-warning col-md-12">    

            <span ng-bind="emp.employeeName"></span> <b>:</b>
            <span ng-bind="emp.employeePhoneNumber"></span>

        </div>
        <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="Employees.length" items-per-page="pageSize"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for delaying.Here is my working **JSFiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/neslisahozdemir/khbbbe47/4/

Comment: please create a jsfiddle once.

Comment: i updated @ManishSingh

Comment: I think its working fine!

Comment: thanks for replaying,but its not search other pages @Viplock

Comment: now its a bit confusing , what does " when I want to filter from other page it does not filter and shows nothing" mean ?

Comment: does it mean it only filters the data of the same page. on which we are ? not the other pages .

Comment: yes, i meant that.. @Viplock

Comment: @NeslişahÖzdemir does the answer satisfy your requirment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood your query i think you will find your solution by changing the sequence of filter .

try using

```
 <tr ng-repeat="emp in Employees  | filter: filterText|orderBy: 'employeeName' |start: (currentPage-1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize" class="alert alert-warning col-md-12">
```

For now filter is working page wise(mean if you type in "C" you will find data on page 1,2 one record each)

After the change in sequence of filter you will get the data in same page(at 1st page 2 records) for filter text "C".

Find updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey7d8zsq/)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem thank you very much,however it caused another situation.. I filter correctly but, when I go to the another page it still does not filter.. Do you have any suggestions? @Viplock

Comment: here you mixing two things . either you can filter the data page wise , or you can filter the data as a whole. actually after the filter your page count should be reduced because your data is filtered and it will fill only 2 page(for example). what you was doing before was page wise filter , and what i suggested is filter as a whole.

Comment: you can check your fiddle and my updated fiddle by putting "C" in filter field and can check the difference of working